# How do I permanently delete a VLAN?

Tags: vlan

If a switch has a VLAN, and we delete the VLAN by the `no vlan` command, then we reboot the switch, we again see the VLAN. How do we permanently delete this VLAN  with commands?

Comment: What is the switch model and configuration?

Comment: It depends on the make and model and software version of the switch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided us with the switch model and configuration. If you provide that information, we can help you determine why the VLAN gets added to your switch.

If you have a Cisco switch, there are several possibilities for why the removed VLAN reappears. You need to make sure that no interfaces (physical or virtual) are configured to use the VLAN, and if you are using VTP, that could be allowing the VLAN, and you would need to use pruning after making sure that no interface use the VLAN. If you are seeing the VLAN with the `show vlan` command, it could be that a trunk is allowing the VLAN, and you can limit that on your trunks with the `switchport trunk allowed vlan` command (manual pruning).

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing individual interfaces and seeing that they're said to be on a certain VLAN, you can configure those interfaces to remove them: `conf t` -> `int fa(x)/(y)` -> `no vlan (z)` and this can alleviate VLAN issues related to those specific interfaces.

Answer (score -3):

vlan.dat is stored in the flash not nvram.

```
switch#delete flash:vlan.dat
```

Comment: That will remove all the VLAN information on a switch, and that may cause more problems. Also, if using VTP, then VTP will restore the VLANs.

Comment: The question is "How do we permanently delete this VLAN with commands?"

Comment: Your solution will remove all the VLAN information, and there may be 20 good VLANs, and one VLAN that needs to be removed, but you will remove the 20 good VLANs, too. If VTP is used, then all the VLAN information will be restored by VTP, even the VLAN to be removed.

Comment: Yes its true, it will remove all the VLAN information. But, he ask why the VLAN not disappear after a reboot, and the answer is because VLAN stored in the flash rom. so the command to remove the VLAN is switch#delete flash:vlan.dat :)

Comment: But the VLAN could come back after reboot if there are any ports in that VLAN, or the switch is using VTP. VTP will rebuild the vlan.dat file each time the switch come up. if the revision number doesn't match the current revision number in VTP.

Comment: This is clearly not the answer to the question on how to delete **A** VLAN, not ALL VLANs